# How to center a form in the container? Using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flex, I have a container and want to have a form inside. This is what it looks like now.
[image]

so,inside that blue container I want the form to look nice, and centered. The blue container is a flex. This is what I have inside that blue container:

```
<div class="formulario">
    <form>
        First name:
        <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
        Last name:
        <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
        Email :
        <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Username:
        <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        Password:
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is the css

```
.formulario {
    background-color: blue;
    flex : 3;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    align-items: center;
    form{
        /*margin:3px; */
    }
}
```

I would like to center those forms, and also ideally space them out more a little bit, and also make them bigger relative to the container.

Comment: If you are learning flexbox, this interactive learning resource is really helpful to learn what you can do with flexbox. https://flexboxfroggy.com/. It will seem a bit silly, but it helped me learn flexbox really quickly.

Answer (score 1):

```css
 
.formulario{
background-color: blue;
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="formulario">
    <form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>First name:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Last name:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="lastname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Email:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Username:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Flexbox and CSS Grid:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 300px;
}

header {
  background: orange;
  height: 30px;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

main .blue {
  background: rgb(60, 120, 230);
  flex: 10;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

main .red {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}

.formulario > form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-gap: 7px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <div class="blue">
    <div class="formulario">
      <form>
        First name:
        <input type="text" name="firstname"> Last name:
        <input type="text" name="lastname"> Email :
        <input type="text" name="email"> Username:
        <input type="text" name="username"> Password:
        <input type="password" name="password">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</main>
```